# Get callback after height animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/7bwMj/) I tried to run some code after height animation

```
<button id="btn1">Animate height</button>
<div id="box"style="background:#98bf21;height:100px;width:100px;margin:6px;"></div>

$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#btn1").click(function () {
    $("#box").animate({height:"300px"});
  });

  var x = $('#box').height();
  if(x == 300){alert('animation is finished');}
});
```

I can't place the code which I want to run after height animation into animate method callback cause the animating box script is placed in one document and code which I want to run in other.

Comment: When you say other document, what do you mean? Other HTML document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event-driven JavaScript a la jQuery:

```
//file 1
$("#box").animate({height:"300px"},function() {
 $(this).trigger('myBoxFinishedAnimatingHeight');
});

//file 2
$('#box').on('myBoxFinishedAnimatingHeight',function() {
 //your code
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use jquery [.promise().done](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn1").click(function () {
        $("#box").animate({
            height: "300px"
        }).promise().done(function () {
            alert('animation is finished');
        });;
    })
});
```

or separately like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btn1").click(function () {
        $("#box").animate({
            height: "300px"
        });

        $("#box").promise().done(function () {
            alert('animation is finished');
        });
    })
});
```

<kbd>**[Fixed Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TheBanana/7bwMj/7/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `complete` property as a callback function:

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

From [http://api.jquery.com/animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7bwMj/6/)

Comment: I think thats what he is referring to when he says he cant place it into the animation callback.

Comment: @Manolo I can't use it because $("#box").animate({height:"300px"}) is placed in one controller of my application and in another controller i must run some code after finish of box animation

Comment: Why don't you add the whole code to the new controller?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#adjest").animate({"height":"300px"},1000);
$("#adjest").promise().done(
   function() {
        alert("done");
    }
);
```

i would use promise and done, if you can't run it inside animate(). 
see here

http://jsfiddle.net/5p8Ww/

Answer (score 0):

You could name space your file and call the fucntion...

```
var NameSpace = Namespace || {};

NameSpace.yourFunction() {
    //Do stuff...
}
```

Then in your html/other_file

```
.animate( properties , 1000, ease, NameSpace.yourFunction())
```